# Proving a probability inequality

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I am finding difficulty with the following proof---

Prove ,if $A_1,A_2,……,A_n$ are $n$ events
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\cap\dots\cap A_n)\geq 1-P(\overline{A_1})- P(\overline{A_2})-\dots- P(\overline{A_n}).$$

My attempt----
I tried to use the Sieve formula(Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion).According to it
$$ P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots\cap A_n)=1-(P(\overline{A_1})+ P(\overline{A_2})+\dots-+P(\overline{A_n}))+ ( P(\overline{A_1})\cap P(\overline{A_2})+ P(\overline{A_2}\cap P(\overline{A_3})+\dots P(\overline{A_(n-1)}\cap P(\overline{A_n}))-\dots+(-1)^nP(A_1)\cap P(A_2)\cap\dots\cap P(A_n)$$
I could not understand how to prove from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. We have that 
$$P(B_1\cup B_2)=P(B_1)+P(B_2)-P(B_1\cap B_2)\leq P(B_1)+P(B_2).$$
Hence, inductively, we find that
$$P(B_1\cup \dots \cup B_n)\leq P(B_1)+P(B_2)+\dots +P(B_n).$$
Now,  by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),
$$P(A_1\cap \dots\cap A_n)=1-P(\overline{A_1}\cup \dots \cup \overline{A_n}).$$
Can you take it from here?